# Curl allows application/x-www-form-urlencoded without actually encoding, is it valid?

Tags: encoding, curl, post

`curl -X POST [::1]:1024 -d 你好` allows to send non-ASCII without percent encoding, is it valid?

Comment: You can simplify with: `curl '[::1]:1024' -d '你好'` because `-d` implies a `POST` already. If your terminal use `UTF8` encoding, `cURL` **can** `url encode` it on the fly. Usually with `--data-urlencode.` What is the response of the server?